# Ajax Paging in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I use codeigniter pagination also here i use ajax to search so that the paging does not works. While click the paging link the full page is get reloaded .Actually i am not familiar with ajax so i dont know how this problem can be solved.Any help is appreciated.

> Controller

```
public function chrgs_ajs_result()
{
    $type = $this->input->post('catg');
    $sdate = $this->input->post('start_date');
    $edate = $this->input->post('end_date');

    $result['error'] = "";

    $result['res'] = "";

    $result['res'] = $this->chrgs_edit_report_model->get_edit_amount($type,$sdate,$edate);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'index.php/payment_edit/chrgs_ajs_result';

    $config['total_rows'] = count($result['res']);

    $config['per_page'] = 15;

    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    $result['res'] = $this->chrgs_edit_report_model->get_edit_amount($type,$sdate,$edate,$config["per_page"], $page);

    $result["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    //$result['res'] = $this->chrgs_edit_report_model->get_edit_amount($type,$sdate,$edate);
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($result['res']);
    if (!empty($result['res'])) 
    {
        $this->load->view('edit_charg_ajax_result',$result);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Result Found";
    }
}
```

> Ajax Result page

```
<table border="1" class="mainTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr> <?php if (isset($links)) { echo $links; } ?> </tr>
<tr style="background-color:#F2FAFF;color:#660">

    <td width="3%">Sl No</td>
    <td width="8%">Track Number</td>
    <td width="8%">Old <?php echo $type; ?></td>
    <td width="8%">New <?php echo $type; ?></td>
    <td width="30%">Reason</td>
    <td width="10%">Date</td>
    <td width="10%">Requested By</td>
    <td width="10%">Approved By</td>
    <td width="10%">Approved IP</td>

</tr>
<?php
$i = 1; 
foreach ($res as $value) 
{
?>
<tr>

    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['track_no']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['old_value']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['new_value']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['reason']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['added_on']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['requested_by']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['approved_by']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['ip']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php 
$i++;
} ?>
```

> Main Result page

```
<section>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left: 2%;">
        <div class="box">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="form">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="col-md-12 row div1">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4" style="margin-left: 80px;">
              <label style="margin-top: 20px;"><b>Types:</b></label>
                <div class="input-group" id="error">
                  <select class="form-control" id="catg" name="catg" style="width: 134%; border-radius: 5px;">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="charges">Charges</option>
                    <option value="delivery_at">Delivery_at</option>
                    <option value="doc_country">Doc_country</option>
                    <option value="doctype">Doctype</option>
                    <option value="mfa">Mfa</option>
                    <option value="package">Package</option>
                    <option value="sub_package">Sub_package</option>
                  </select> 
                </div>                  
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3" >
              <label class="lmarg"><b>Start Date:</b></label>
              <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> </div>               
                <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control datepicker">
              </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3" style="margin-left: 2px;">
              <label class="lmarg"><b>End Date:</b></label>
              <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> </div>               
                <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="form-control datepicker">
              </div>                    
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label label class="lmarg" style="visibility: hidden;">search</label>
        <div class="col-md-1 input-group">
          <input type="button" class="btn pull-right" id="search_charge_edit" value="search">
          </div>
         </div>
     </div>
         </div>
         </fieldset> 
        </form>
        <div style="margin-top: 3%;margin-right: 1%;">
        <div id="result" ></div>

      </div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#search_charge_edit").on("click",function(){

  var controller_function = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/payment_edit/chrgs_ajs_result";
  var post_data = $("#form").serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:controller_function,
    data:post_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
      //alert(data);
      //$('#form').trigger("reset");
      $('#result').html(data);
  }

  });

});
```

Comment: if your pagination is not much bigger, I prefer you to use [Bootstrap Datatables](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap). Which has inbuilt search  too

Comment: no it is bigger searching

Comment: 10000 < can use that. No issues

Comment: actually i want ajax pagination

Comment: For make pagination in url ` var controller_function` you must add number of page https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination

Comment: I prefer Datatables with Ajax https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html